# Excel xlsm file corrupt?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I have a problem with an macro spreadsheet. The ActiveX buttons are disabled and all the code is missing from my project. Trying to add code to my project causes an error.

[Here is the file.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/onzlrz8g7x4n5zr/NeilCo%20Statement%20Import.xlsm?dl=0)

Comment: Restore from backup.

Comment: I created a new file and it works fine. It's a keystroke program with 20 lines of code. I would be interested in finding out if anyone can give me a technical explanation of what happened to corrupt the file or if there is a way to recover it.

Answer (score 0):

If restoring a previous version is not possible

- FYI Vista+ has "[previous versions of files](http://www.dummies.com/computers/operating-systems/windows-xp-vista/how-to-retrieve-previous-versions-of-files-in-windows-vista/)" feature in users' Document folders
- since it's an invoice template of some kind, you probably have old copies lying everywhere

you can save the file to a different format (worksheet without macros) and back to force Excel to regenerate everything, so you can then add the code back.

---

There's an [OOXML validator](https://ooxmlvalidator.codeplex.com/) out there, it can tell you what specifically is wrong (in OOXML standard's terms).

How and if it's possible to fix corruption depends on what is wrong. Typically, corruption results from an interrupted write (e.g. the program or the machine crashed or an error occurred midway) or transfer or a disk sector failure - i.e. it's simply a loss of some part of the file and thus cannot be restored without knowing exactly what was (supposed to be) in it. So, it's usually not worth it wasting time trying to "recover" lost data 'cuz it's simply not there.

The recipe to avoid loss of important data is backing it up regularly (for work documents, a nightly backup is the standard and best solution).
Windows is bundled with a backup program since at least 2k. There are enough guides out there how to set up and operate it, e.g. [Configure automatic backups in Windows 7, 8 and 10 | www.winhelp.us](https://www.winhelp.us/configure-automatic-backup-in-windows-7.html).

Comment: I had a backup but it acts the same way. I took care of the .exd problem a while ago, but this is specific to the file. It's not a huge loss but I would really like to find out what happened. I have another project with 24k lines of code. If it stops working I won't be able to do payroll. Yikes!

Comment: I created a new file and it works fine. It's a keystroke program with 20 lines of code. I would be interested in finding out if anyone can give me a technical explanation of what happened to corrupt the file or if there is a way to recover it.

Comment: @NeilB see the update